# How to utilize Request to integration test async Koa Node API

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, jestjs, koa

I'm working on my first real-world Node project using Koa2 and [Request](https://github.com/request/request) for making RESTful API calls to a 3rd party. The Koa service itself is relatively simple, but I'm trying to write an integration test for it using [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/).  I've found [examples of using Jest with Supertest/Superagent](http://www.albertgao.xyz/2017/05/24/how-to-test-expressjs-with-jest-and-supertest/), but I cant find how I'd write the equivalent test using ONLY Jest and Request as the http client.  Below is the Jest/Supertest example...

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../../src/app')
describe('Test the root path', () => {
    test('It should response the GET method', async () => {
      const response = await request(app).get('/');
      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    });
})
```

It seems like I should be able to just use Request to do the same thing that supertest/superagent is doing here, but I cant find any example.  Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Supertest looks magical because you can pass it your `app` and somehow that just works.

Under the hood, Supertest justs starts listening and configures the underlying request to use the address as a base url.

I'm using Axios here as an example, I don't use Request but it should be easy enough to adjust.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const app = require('../../src/app')
const server = app.listen() // random port

const url = `http://127.0.0.1:${server.address().port}`

const request = axios.create({ baseURL: url })

describe('Test the root path', () => {
    test('It should response the GET method', async () => {
      const response = await request.get('/')
      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200)
    });
})
```